# AttributeError: module 'pandoc' has no attribute 'main'

Tags: python-3.x, pandoc, pypandoc

Python 3.8.2

```
python -m pip install pandoc

python -m pandoc
```

After installing pandoc and trying to run it with valid arguments, the following exception pops up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandoc\__main__.py", line 11, in <module>
    pandoc.main()
AttributeError: module 'pandoc' has no attribute 'main'
```

Please help me fix the issue :)